# How do I `svn diff` while excluding a directory?

Tags: svn, unix

I'm trying to generate a diff between two revisions of a specific folder in SVN. However, one subdirectory has a lot of messy and irrelevant changes that I don't want included in the diff.  Any idea on how I can accomplish this?

I thought perhaps I could try something like this?

```
C:\>svn diff -r 58:64 `svn ls http://svn-server/svn/my-app/branches/prototype | grep -v 'doc/'`
```

That doesn't seem to work though:

```
svn: E155007: 'C:\cygwin\home\myusername\.gitignore' is not a working copy
```

.gitignore is one of the files returned by `svn ls http://svn-server/svn/my-app/branches/prototype | grep -v 'doc/'`:

```
C:\>svn ls http://svn-server/svn/my-app/branches/prototype | grep -v 'doc/'
.gitignore
.project
.rspec
.rvmrc
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
README.rdoc
Rakefile
app/
config/
config.ru
db/
features/
lib/
log/
public/
script/
spec/
test/
vendor/
```

Comment: What do you get from just the `svn ls ... /doc'`?

Comment: @HewWolff I've added the result above ^^

Comment: Actually I think I might have an idea of how to fix this, but I'm not quite sure how to do it... is there a way to prepend 'http://svn-server/svn/my-app/branches/prototype/' to all the lines found by `svn ls http://svn-server/svn/my-app/branches/prototype | grep -v '/doc'`?

Comment: A very similar question has been asked in another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414954/how-do-i-exclude-certain-files-from-a-svn-diff) where I have provided a code of a bash [script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414954/how-do-i-exclude-certain-files-from-a-svn-diff/16420707#16420707) that supplied with a `svn diff` output can exclude all the changes from the files matching the given pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you CD into a local working copy of the folder and try the command again.  Then "svn diff" should be able to make sense of the local paths output from "svn ls".