# How do I exclude certain files from a svn diff?

Tags: svn, diff

I'm using `svn diff -c 789` to show the changes made in revision 789 of our software, but it's showing a lot of files I don't care about, in particular test files. How can I exclude certain files from the diff, for example all files which match the pattern `*Test.java`?

I'm using Cygwin on Windows, if that's important.

Comment: It is not possible to exclude any files from `svn diff`. What you can do is to use a tool that enables to filter (also exclude) the changes from the files you do not care about or write a script that will parse the output of `svn diff` removing the changes from the files you want to exclude. If you are interested in such script please provide more details about your environment - operating system and shell.

Comment: @Adam I'm using Cygwin on Windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As `svn diff` does not allow to exclude specific files from the output, below is a BASH script that can be used to achieve that.

It takes two arguments:

- `file` with an `svn diff` output
- `pattern` of the files to be excluded (e.g. `test/*`)

and prints the content of the `file` without the changes from the files matching `pattern`.

```
#!/bin/bash

test $# -ne 2 && echo "Usage: $0 svn_diff_file exclude_pattern" && exit 1

ignore=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo $line | grep -q -e "^Index: " && ignore=0
    echo $line | grep -e "^Index: " | grep -q -e "^Index: $2" && ignore=1
    test $ignore -eq 0 && echo "$line"
done < $1
```

---

**Update**

I just came across a tool that does this job: [filterdiff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/filterdiff). It's usage is very similar to the above script:

`filterdiff svn_diff_file -x exclude_pattern`

Comment: This is good but in case of huge diff files it can be better to only call `svn diff` on the desired files rather than filter the diff of everything. See Victor's answer below if you have such issues.

Answer (score 4):

By the way, remember that the svn diff commands works as others commands following the in Unix modular philosophy where each command has a standard input and ouput.
You can genare your own customize script for listing files you want to include redirect the output of that script to the svn diff commands via the use of pipes and then redirect your output of diff to the desired file you want to create.
Just to be more clear : follow this example

```
svn diff `cat change_list.txt` > patch.diff
```

in `change_list.txt` the are the files you want to include in the diff separated by space. For example, the content of the file could be this :

> "domain/model/entity.java"
>
> "web_app/controllers/controller.java"

So following this approach, the only dificult of your problem is reduced to implement a script that like Adam generously wrote above.

Hope it helps!

Vic.

Comment: This is the simplest option. You can use `find` to specify files to include in the diff: `svn diff $(find . -type f -name '*.js')`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

```
FILES=$(svn status some_dir|grep ^M|cut -b2-|grep -v dir_to_remove)
test -n "$FILES" && svn diff "$FILES"
```