# how to make svn diff to ignore binary files

Tags: svn, version-control, diff

My svn version is 1.8.8, OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm transferring a project from ant to maven, so I delete the jar files in lib directory. When I created a svn diff file for code review, I find the diff file contains lots of binary compare result in it, the content of deleted jar files.

I added "*.jar = svn:mime-application/octet-stream" to ~/.subversion/config, but it didn't work.

How can I make svn diff ignore binary files?

Answer (score 1):

This [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16420707/1023562) says you can not make `svn diff` ignore some files, but you can do following:

First, make diff file:

```
svn diff > svn_diff_file
```

Second, use [filterdiff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/filterdiff) to filter file created above:

```
filterdiff svn_diff_file -x *.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even easier without any intermediary file:

```
svn diff | filterdiff -x *.jar | colordiff
```

colordiff was only used to see in colors what was added or removed.